# CacheCow and OData caching, how to invalidate PUT/PATCH '/Cars(1)' for GET ALL query '/Cars' as well?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, odata

When using CacheCow everything is working great as far as caching goes, except when I do a put/patch/other update to a specific item like `/Cars(1)` it only invalidates the get query for `/Cars(1)` and not the parent Get All of `/Cars`

I've been looking and the documentation seems to be pretty sparse with the wiki just having how to use other types of persistent storage and not really any customization.

I don't mind having to call like `Cacher.Invalidate("Cars")` or something like that in each of the methods, but I'm not sure what I'd have to call as the CacheCow settings all take place in the config and not per controller so I'm not sure what I'd have to be calling (if a method even exists).

Comment: You can open an issue to the creator of the library at [github](https://github.com/aliostad/CacheCow/issues). He's a nice guy and responses very quickly.